# c# Selenium clicking the matching result

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I want to click on the video that matches the channel name according to the results after searching on youtube, but I do the channel match, but I can click the channel, not the video. i want Channel Name Or Url When it matches, its video is opened.

```
var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.images", 2);
options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
options.AddArgument("disable-infobars");
options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
            
var driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.youtube.com/");

       
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500));            
var elementsWithSearchID = wait.Until((driver) => driver.FindElements(By.Id("search")));
var search = elementsWithSearchID.Where(e => e.TagName == "input").FirstOrDefault();

search.SendKeys("Hello\n");
Thread.Sleep(2000);
IWebElement channel = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"text\"]/a[contains(@href, '/channel/UCV1Nlv5cOSB--hEjRVo4mUA')]"));
channel.Click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code and run it, so you want to open video which match with your channel name, right?
so you need to first take the link which match with your channel name and after that put below code .

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href='/watch?v=VKIiCOZ2Eo4']")).Click();
```

instead of

```
IWebElement channel = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"text\"]/a[contains(@href, '/channel/UCV1Nlv5cOSB--hEjRVo4mUA')]"));
```

Comment: Well, if my video is at the bottom of the list, that is, at the bottom of the scroll, it will fail.
and also, the code you provide does not only match the channel. it just finds that video directly. I want to match the channel first and then I want the video to be clicked. I'm new to c # I'd appreciate it if you could help.